# Evaluating $\int\,\cos(x)\cos(\omega x)\,dx$ using trigonometric addition formulas

Tags: integration, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, arithmetic

I'm looking to solve the integral

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2}\, \cos(x)\cos(\omega x)\,dx$$

by rewriting the terms using the trigonometric addition formulaes.

It should end up as:

$$\left.\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\omega \cos(x) \sin(\omega x)-\sin(x)\cos(\omega x)}{\omega^2-1}\right|_{x=-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{x=\frac{\pi}{2}}.$$

Need it to solve similar problems when evalutating integrals using Fourier integrals.

Comment: I inserted what I think is the standard evaluation bar. If you prefer something else, you can probably glean the knowledge of what I've done to get whatever symbol you do prefer.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\cos{(x)}\cos{(\omega x)}=\frac{\cos{((\omega-1)x))}+\cos{((\omega+1)x)}}{2}$.

Comment: That's a nice hint!  I wish I had time to go through a derivation of it...

Comment: Just a basic application of the usual formula $2 \cos(a) \cos(b) = \cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b)$, which is itself a basic application of $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$, a fairly *standard* formula.